# kafka error handler not being called when topic doesnt exist for listener

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spring-kafka

we have a specific case we want to handle with an email logger (instead of just to the console). When our consumers/listeners are referencing a non-existent topic.

container factory configuration:

```
@Bean
    public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
        ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, Object> factory = new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
        factory.setConsumerFactory(new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(consumerStringObjectProperties(), new StringDeserializer(),
                new JsonDeserializer<>(EventUtils.createObjectMapper())));

        KafkaErrorHandler kafkaErrorHandler = new KafkaErrorHandler();
        factory.setCommonErrorHandler(kafkaErrorHandler);
        return factory;
    }
```

Error Handler:

```
public class KafkaErrorHandler implements CommonErrorHandler {
    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(KafkaErrorHandler.class);
    @Autowired(required = false)
    EmailLogger emailLogger;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void handleRecord(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecord<?, ?> record, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
        logger.error("error", thrownException);

        CommonErrorHandler.super.handleRecord(thrownException, record, consumer, container);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void handleBatch(Exception thrownException, ConsumerRecords<?, ?> data, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container,
            Runnable invokeListener) {
        logger.error("error", thrownException);

        CommonErrorHandler.super.handleBatch(thrownException, data, consumer, container, invokeListener);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void handleRemaining(Exception thrownException, List<ConsumerRecord<?, ?>> records, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container) {
        logger.error("error", thrownException);

        CommonErrorHandler.super.handleRemaining(thrownException, records, consumer, container);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void handleOtherException(Exception thrownException, Consumer<?, ?> consumer, MessageListenerContainer container, boolean batchListener) {
        String msg = "Error from kafka!";
        logger.error(msg, thrownException);
        if (null != emailLogger) {
            emailLogger.reportError(getClass().getName(), msg, thrownException);
        }

        CommonErrorHandler.super.handleOtherException(thrownException, consumer, container, batchListener);
    }
    
}
```

listener:

```
@KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.topics.events}'.split(',')}", groupId = "${application.group}", containerFactory = "kafkaListenerContainerFactory")
    public void relayEvents(@Payload(required = false) Event event) {
        try {
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(event);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Failed to publish event to spring application event publisher", e);
        }
    }
```

But when I start the service and the topic doesnt exist, it only prints to the console.  None of my breakpoints in the KafkaErrorHandler are hit nor is it logged via the logger statements I have there!

error when topic doesnt exist:

> 08:06:41.206
> [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]
> WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-myapp-cloud-1, groupId=myapp-cloud] Received unknown
> topic or partition error in fetch for partition
> myapp2.settings.events-0 08:06:41.279
> [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]
> WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.Fetcher - [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-myapp-cloud-1, groupId=myapp-cloud] Received unknown
> topic or partition error in fetch for partition
> myapp2.settings.events-0 08:06:41.343
> [org.springframework.kafka.KafkaListenerEndpointContainer#0-0-C-1]
> WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - [Consumer
> clientId=consumer-myapp-cloud-1, groupId=myapp-cloud] Error while
> fetching metadata with correlation id 201 :
> {myapp2.settings.events=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}

Comment: `UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION` is not an exception causing event. This is expected behavior. Use `@Bean NewTopic` if you want to create them before the consumer starts

Comment: i dont want the topic to auto create.   I just want to capture this error and report it.

Comment: Alright, then you need to use an `AdminClient.describeTopics` call to properly capture unknown topics (and/or partitions) rather than a consumer with its error handler.

Comment: side note, we are using julie to create topics so a consumer with an unknown topic is an error case for us.  It gets really hairy trying to do that, because with the kafka listener annotation it needs to be done in the init/postcontruct method of our consumer/listener service which isnt a good place to be calling out

Comment: Like I said, you'll need to check the topic existence separately. If they exist, then you can [manually start the listeners](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/html/#kafkalistener-lifecycle)

Comment: The error handler is only for handling errors processing received records; this error occurs way before that.